# Set a templates Field as Shared or Unversioned Programmatically

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I'm using Sitecore Version 8.1 and trying to create `Templates`, `Fields` and `Items` programmatically(to ensure some scenarios in case item/template not exist) and I'm trying to set specific template's field as `shared` or `unversioned` but couldn't because:

`bool TemplateFieldItem.Shared` attribute has only `getter` method (there is no setter).

My code:

```cs
var icon = PageTemplate.AddField("Icon", "Data");
using (new EditContext(icon.InnerItem)) 
{ 
    icon.Type = "Image"; 
    icon.Sortorder = 3; 
    icon.Shared = false;
}
```

So my problem is only in  `icon.Shared = false;` as well as `icon.Unversioned = false;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set it on the inner item. In theory changing field from version to unversioned or from shared to unshared is a complex process, but assuming that you're adding those fields and there should be no items with them yet, you should be ok,

Use:

```cs
icon.InnerItem[TemplateFieldIDs.Unversioned] = "1"; // or null
```

or:

```cs
icon.InnerItem[TemplateFieldIDs.Shared] = "1"; // or null
```

Comment: In your answer you allude to there being complications if items already exist based on your templates. Could you elaborate on this? Would I need to iterate those items and remove their local values for the fields in question?

Comment: @GregB I haven't tried this on my own in any production environment. But the data for shared/versioned/unversioned fields is stored in different tables in sql. You can find some info here: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/045873